# pacman: difference between sync, local, package and files databases

Tags: arch-linux, pacman, manjaro

`man pactree` says:

> -s, --sync
>
> Read package data from sync databases instead of local database.

What is the difference between the two, and when would I prefer to use one over the other?

`man pacman` also mentions:

- `package database`
- `files database`

How do these fit into the picture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The local database is the list of all installed packages, the sync database is the list of all possible packages (determined by the repositories enabed in `/etc/pacman.conf`).

So, you would pass the `-s` switch to `pactree` if you wanted to see the dependency tree for an uninstalled package.

The files database is pacman's native replacement for the `pkgfile` utility; it lets you reverse search for the name of the package that owns a particular file. Both tools require that you update the files database for an accurate result. See `man pacman`:

> -F, --files
>              Query the files database. This operation allows you to look for packages owning certain files or display files owned by certain packages. Only
>              packages that are part of your sync databases are searched. See File Options below.