# What different between pacman -Sy and pacman -Fy?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

Using pacman I can update package databases using the following command **pacman -Sy** or **pacman -Fy** what is the difference between this keys of pacman and what is better to use?

Comment: Relating: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/343414/315749

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at [the man page](https://archlinux.org/pacman/pacman.8.html) you see that:

- `-S` is for installing packages.
- `-F` is for querying the files database.
- `-y` refreshes the package database, and it's valid with both `-S` and `-F`.

The two major options (`-S` and `-F`) do very different things, but in both cases `-y` means "update the package database before you do anything else".

Comment: thank you, but me it is not quite clear what kind of database files are requested when using the -F key?

Comment: @Besha If you'll read the man page, it's querying the database of the repositories that hold the packages for a files that are owned by a specific package.